# symfony many normalizers for one entity

Tags: symfony

I have several user roles with access to orders and controllers for each of them. Are there ways to change the normalizer for one entity, for example...

**in this action i need to get the normalizer for the courier:**

```
    ## CourierController
     /**
     * @Rest\Get()
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        $orders = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Order::class)
            ->findBy(['courier' => $this->getUser()->getCourierAccount()]);
        $data = $serializer->normalize($orders); // <--------- 1) how to choose the right normalizer?
        return $this->json($data);
    }
```

**But in this i need for something like 'ClientOrderNormalizer'**

```
    ## ClientController
     /**
     * @Rest\Get()
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        $orders = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Order::class)
            ->findBy(['client' => $this->getUser()->getClientAccount()]);
        $data = $serializer->normalize($orders); // <--------- 2) how to choose the right normalizer?
        return $this->json($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Using Serialization Groups Annotations -> [look here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations)

2) Create custom DTO then serialize this object for a response.

Example of how to create custom DTO.

```
final class SignInResponse implements ResponseInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", description="Token.")
     */
    private string $token;

    public function __construct(UserSession $userSession)
    {
        $this->token = $userSession->getToken();
    }

    /**
     * Get Token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToken(): string
    {
        return $this->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give advice on how to best convert Entity to Dto?

Comment: @inkrot I like it this way, but this is an individual or team decision. Add an example to answer.